# Swift: Passing data from one form to another, two times in a row: second time refuses to pass

Tags: swift, segue

I'm working on an app that consists of forms, the structure of which goes as follows:

- MainForm (named: CorrosionRate)
- MainForm Continuation (with MainTable - named: CorrosionERMeasurement)
- MainTable Form (with SubTable - named: CorrosionSampleTreatment)
- SubTable Form

The idea, basically, is a table, within a table. Each table has an identifier, the "parent". MainTable's parent is MainForm, and SubTable's parent is MainTable.

We pass this between the forms via `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "CorrosionAddERMeasurementSegue" {
        let vc : CorrosionAddERMeasurementFormViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CorrosionAddERMeasurementFormViewController
        vc.selectedCorrosionRateID = self.selectedCorrosionRateID
    }
}
```

For the first part, it works fine. I can pass MainForm's ID to MainTable Form, ensuring that no matter what MainTable's actual ID is, it will always belong to MainForm.

Here's where things get dicey:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddCorrosionSampleTreatmentSegue" {
        let vc : CorrosionAddSampleTreatmentFormViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CorrosionAddSampleTreatmentFormViewController
        vc.selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID = self.selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID
    }
}
```

When the next xib loads, I immediately print the value of `selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID` which returns `nil`.

This is the code for switching to the next form:

```
func addSampleButtonPressed() {
    print("Add Button Pressed. Selected Corrosion Measurements: \(self.selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID)")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CorrosionAddSampleTreatmentSegue", sender: self)
}
```

And that does print out the correct parent ID value. Here's the opening statements of the SubTable Form:

```
class CorrosionAddSampleTreatmentFormViewController: BaseViewController, SampleTreatmentFormViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var corrosionAddSampleFormView : SurfaceThermalSamplingAddSamplingView!
    var selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("Selected ID from FormCorrosionER is: \(self.selectedCorrosionErMeasurementID)")
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Nothing to suggest that the value is being erased.

Is there anything I need to check? Perhaps there's a limit to how deep I can go into segues? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly, I believe your segue identifiers are mis-matched

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CorrosionAddSampleTreatmentSegue", sender: self)
```

vs

```
if segue.identifier == "AddCorrosionSampleTreatmentSegue" {
```

If the first line is supposed to lead to the second, the identifiers need to be identical.

Comment: I hate it when that kind of thing happens :(